# Filter SQL queries on the XML column using XPath/XQuery

Tags: sql, xpath, xquery

I'm having a table with one XML column. I'd like to filter out the rows where a specific attribute in the XML match a string, essentially doing a WHERE or HAVING.

The table looks something like this

```
| id | xml |
```

And the XML something similar to

```
<xml>
  <info name="Foo">
    <data .../>
  </info>
<xml>
```

I want to get all ids where the @name attribute matched a value.

I have been able to do the following:

```
SELECT id, xml.query('data(/xml/info/@name)') as Value
FROM Table1
WHERE CAST(xml.query('data(/xml/info/@name)') as varchar(1024)) = @match
```

But it's incredibly slow.

There must be a better way of filtering on the output of the query.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, I'd also suggest making sure you've got indexes on your XML columns. >[XML Indexes Overview (SQLServerPedia.com)](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/XML_Indexes_Overview)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found it. Instead of using query() I should be using [exist()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx).

My query would then be

```
SELECT id, xml.query('data(/xml/info/@name)') as Value
FROM Table1
WHERE xml.exist('/xml/info/[@name=sql:variable("@match")]') = 1
```