# How to filter xml nodes in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

How to add second condition to the following query?

```
SELECT c.value('@tray','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  FROM @L_XML.nodes('/XDOC/DOC[@TYPE="Q"]') T(c)
```

so that I could filter on attribute: type = Q or S?

Where Can I find a detailed manual about xml nodes?

Comment: A good resource is this book: Pro SQL Server 2008 XML (Expert's Voice) (Amazon: http://goo.gl/Kx7V2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.value('@tray','VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @L_XML.nodes('/XDOC/DOC[@TYPE = ("Q", "S")]') T(c)
```

Comment: For any here wondering: To Filter on an Element Value instead (i.e. `<Type>Q</Type>`), you would omit the At-Symbol (`@`) for `Type` in the Filter above (**if** `Type` was an Element and not an Attribute).

Comment: **WARNING:** Using the XPath/XQuery Filter like this _**is**_ **Case-Sensitive**.  So (unless your XML source is 100% pure and every possible Element-Value you expect to parse is enforced with an XSD policy), you may be better off either including the lower-case variants `("Q", "S", "q", "s")`, or extracting the Value from XML and using a normal T-SQL Predicate `IN`-Clause to filter your results down.  You could also try including the Upper-Case Function.  For an **Element**, I was able to make it work with: `[upper-case(TYPE[1]) = ("Q", "S")]`

Answer (score 1):

A very good starting point is [SQLXML](http://sqlxml.org/) where an exhaustive list of basic reads and writes are covered on a *How To* basis. Quite handy and certainly worth a bookmark in my book!

In regard to your first question: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729973/filter-sql-queries-on-the-xml-column-using-xpath-xquery), that might give you what you're looking for. I think your problem might be in the quotes.

Comment: The problem is how to add second condition to the existing one. Neither don't know if it is possible, nor what is the right syntax...

Comment: SQLXML has not been updated in about ten years and only seems to address SQL 2000.